# AWS athena query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have athena log like this: "{"request":"requesturl","time":IntegerValue}"
and how can I extract time value which is of integer type from this.

I read about json_extract but I am not able to use that in this case for extracting integer.

Update: now able to extract time value, but comparing that value to some constant value, it is showing error. Like: where time > 1000, basically I want to fetch request which has time > 1000.

Comment: "but I am not able to use that in this case for extracting integer." - why exactly?

Comment: Also please share the example integer value.

Comment: Please add some sample data, query you are trying and error.

Comment: if you have made time as **varchar** then just cast the time into **int** then compare it.